# Imap nodejs save emails as .pst file

Tags: node.js, imap, nodemailer

I used IMAP package on nodejs and this works perfectly fine.
https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap

```
imap.once('ready', function() {
    openInbox(function(err, box) {
      if (err) return ReE(res, {err:err}) ;
      imap.search([ 'ALL', ['SINCE', 'May 20, 2010'] ], function(err, results) {
        if (err) return ReE(res, {err:err}) ;
        var f = imap.fetch(results, { bodies: '' });
        f.on('message', function(msg, seqno) {
          console.log('Message #%d', seqno);
          var prefix = '(#' + seqno + ') ';
          msg.on('body', async function(stream, info) {
            console.log(prefix + 'Body');
            let name = `${Math.random().toString(36).substring(2)}`;
            stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`${dir}/${name}.txt`));
          });
          msg.once('attributes', function(attrs) {
            console.log(prefix + 'Attributes: %s', inspect(attrs, false, 8));
          });
          msg.once('end', function() {
            console.log(prefix + 'Finished');
          });
        });
        f.once('error', function(err) {
          if (err) return ReE(res, {err:err}) ;
        });
        f.once('end', function() {
          console.log('Done fetching all messages!');
          imap.end();
        });
      });
    });
  });
```

I can read all the emails with the above snippets. but I need to store these emails as .pst file for importing in outlook. is there any way?

Comment: .pst is a proprietary format; however, you may be able to import them if you write out the entire MIME message as a .eml file.  If you need to load more than a couple dozen messages though, this will be quite painful.

Comment: @Max tnx . this file I am generating with imap is MIME format i checked . so the question is Suppose I have MIME formatted .txt file. is this enough for importing to outlook or thunderbird?

Comment: Yep.  Just write it out with a ".eml" ending, and it should open in most email clients.